# Some questions about the contruction of center stable manifolds for cubic NLKG by Lyapunov-Perron method

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation, hyperbolic-dynamics

In [Nakanish & Schlag: Invariant manifolds and Dispersive Hamiltonian Evolution Equations,](https://books.google.com/books?hl=zh-CN&lr=&id=7a8AtzfIB6wC&oi=fnd&pg=PA17&dq=invariant%20manifolds%20and%20dispersive%20hamiltonian%20evolution%20equations&ots=DOqZfBd3Ft&sig=SM0qieIEePJOuanO0HUYc8xRkh8#v=onepage&q=invariant%20manifolds%20and%20dispersive%20hamiltonian%20evolution%20equations&f=false), on theorem 3.22, they use Lyapunov-Perron methods to conctruct center stable manifolds for focusing cubic nonlinear Klein-Gordon equation
\begin{equation}
\partial_{tt} u -\Delta u+ u -u^3=0,  \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
here there are some details of proof I cannot figure out. More precisely, the theorem includes the following result (**and we are now considering only in radial case, i.e. the following functions are all radial**):

- If the solution $(u,\dot u)$ remains into $B_\nu(Q,0)$ for all time $t\ge0$, where $B_\nu (Q,0) \subset \mathbb{H}= H^1 \times L^2$ is a $\nu$ ($\nu \ll 1$) ball with center $(Q,0)$, and $Q$ is the correponding ground state, then they claim that for any forward time $t$, $u(t)$ lies entirely in center stable manifolds (here we do not present the concrete construction of the center stable manifolds), and it suffices to check that
  \begin{align*}
  &\quad \; \lVert (\lambda,\gamma) \rVert_{X_T}
  \\
  &= \lVert \lambda\rVert_{L^1(0,T)} + \lVert \lambda \rVert_{L^\infty(T,\infty)} + \lVert \gamma \rVert_{S_t(0,T)} + \lVert (\gamma,\dot \gamma) \rVert_{L^\infty((T,\infty);H^1 \times L^2)}   \lesssim \nu,
  \tag{1}
  \end{align*}
  where $u=Q+v=Q+ \lambda(t) \rho + \gamma(t,x)$, and $(\gamma,\rho)_{L^2}=0$, $S_t(0,T)= L_t^2 L_x^6 \cap L_t^2 H_x^1$, and $\rho$ is the eigenvector of unique negative eigenvaule of linearized operator $L_+=-\Delta+1 -3Q^2$. And from the construction of center stable manifolds, we can see that
  \begin{equation}
  \lambda(t)
  =e^{-kt} \left(  \lambda(0) + \frac{1}{2k} \int_0^\infty  e^{-ks} N_\rho(v)(s) ds  \right) + \frac{1}{2k}\int_0^\infty e^{-k|t-s|} N_\rho (v) (s) ds ,
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  \gamma(t)= \cos (wt) \gamma(0) + \frac{\sin (wt)} {w} \dot{\gamma}(0 )+ \int_0^t \frac{\sin(t-s) w}{w} N_c(v)(s) ds,
  \end{equation}
  where $w^2=P^+ \circ L_+$, $N_\rho(v)= (\rho,N(v))_{L^2}$, $N_c=P_+ (N(v))$, here $N(v)=3Qv^2+v^3$ and $P^+$ is the spectral projection of $L^+$ onto $(1,\infty)$ (since we can see that $\sigma(L_+)=(1,\infty) \cup \{-k^2\}$ ). And with the properties of $\gamma$, for the second equation above, we have Strichartz estimates
  \begin{equation}
  \lVert \gamma \rVert_{S_t} \lesssim \lVert \gamma(0) \rVert_{H^1} + \lVert \dot \gamma (0) \rVert _{L^2} + \lVert N_c(v) \rVert_{L_t^1 L_x^2}.
  \end{equation}

**My question is simple, and is involved in the following two estimates:** with the preliminaries before, we want to check $(1)$. And they claim the following two inequlities:
\begin{align*}
\lVert \lambda \rVert _{L^1(0,T) \cap L^\infty(T,\infty)} 
&\lesssim \lVert N_\rho\rVert_{L^1(0,T) \cap L^\infty(T,\infty)} \\
&\lesssim \nu+\nu(\lVert \lambda \rVert _{L^1(0,T) \cap L^\infty(T,\infty)}+\lVert \gamma \rVert_{S_t(0,T)} + \lVert \gamma \rVert_{L_t^\infty((0,\infty);H^1 \times L^2)}), 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation}
\lVert \gamma \rVert_{S_t(0,T)}  \lesssim \nu + \nu(\lVert \lambda \rVert_{L^1(0,T)+ \lVert \gamma \rVert_{S_t(0,T)} }),
\end{equation}

uniformly in $T >0$. But how can we check the estimates above, since I always get the higher order of $\lVert \gamma (t)\rVert_{S_t}$ and $\lVert \lambda \rVert_{L^1(0,T)}$ on the right hand side and I can not thrrow them away, which makes me confused.

Some more questions: By orthogonality between $\rho$ and $\gamma$ in $L^2$, it is obvious that $\lVert (\lambda,\dot \lambda) \rVert_{L^\infty} \lesssim \nu$ and $\lVert (\gamma, \dot \gamma) \rVert _{H^1 \times L^2} \lesssim \nu$, I also wonder why they add $L^\infty(T,\infty)$ of $\lambda$ and $L_t^\infty H_x^1(T,\infty)$ of $\gamma$ in $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{X_T}$?